# How to disable rails timezone function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just want to insert data record into tables with no timezone support.How to config it?

That is to say:
the current time is 2010-10-10 15:22:31 in my country/region,I want to the column created_at on the record in the table I just inserted is  2010-10-10 15:22:31.

How to config it?

Comment: why kill the timezone feature. We always get your date with your country. It's more easy to keep it. because after in your production mode you can have some issue with your server timezone etc...

Comment: Because some projects(one java,one php) works with the same db backend.The I want rails app store raw datetime in tables.

Answer (score 1):

Rails converts from your current timezone to the configured db timezone, I suggest you set both `Time.zone = "NZST"` and the db backend time to `ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone = "NZST"` (replace 'NZST' with the timezone that you're in/that your server is set to). Then the timestamps should all match up.

Set both these config options in `config/environments.rb`